# Forecasting plot -adding fitting and validation area

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting, data-visualization

I refer to the link: http://kourentzes.com/forecasting/2016/06/17/how-to-choose-a-forecast-for-your-time-series/#comments

How should i add fitting and validation area in the plot, according to the Fig. 2: ETS and ARIMA forecasts on validation set. The models are fitted only in the first part of the time series and the validation set is used only to assess their performance.

[image]

my dataset (`zz`) as below:

```
     X dataid meter_value
 2015-10-27 19:50:00   1103      183138
 2015-10-27 19:51:00   1103      183138
 2015-10-27 19:52:00   1103      183138
 2015-10-27 19:53:00   1103      183138
 2015-10-27 19:54:00   1103      183138
 2015-10-27 19:55:00   1103      183138
 2015-10-27 19:56:00   1103      183138
 2015-10-27 19:57:00   1103      183138
 2015-10-27 19:58:00   1103      183138
 2015-10-27 19:59:00   1103      183138
 2015-10-27 20:00:00   1103      183138
 2015-10-27 20:01:00   1103      183138
 2015-10-27 20:02:00   1103      183138
 2015-10-27 20:03:00   1103      183138
 2015-10-27 20:04:00   1103      183138
 2015-10-27 20:05:00   1103      183138
 2015-10-27 20:06:00   1103      183138
 2015-10-27 20:07:00   1103      183138
 2015-10-27 20:08:00   1103      183138
 2015-10-27 20:09:00   1103      183138
 :
 2015-12-31 23:59:00   1103      183139.3
```

my R code as below:

```
    start_time <- as.POSIXct("2015-10-27 19:50",format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
    end_time   <- as.POSIXct("2015-10-27 23:59",format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")

    zoo_obj <- zoo(zz$meter_value,
      order.by = seq.POSIXt(from = start_time, to = end_time ,by = "min"))

    str(zoo_obj)
    #‘zoo’ series from 2015-10-27 19:50:00 to 2015-10-27 20:09:00
    #  Data: num [1:20] 183138 183138 183138 183138 183138 ...
    #  Index:  POSIXct[1:20], format: "2015-10-27 19:50:00" "2015-10-27 19:51:00" ...

    mytsTT2 <- ts(zoo_obj)

str(mytsTT2)
#Time-Series [1:20] from 1 to 20: 183138 183138 183138 183138 183138 ...
# - attr(*, "index")= POSIXct[1:20], format: "2015-10-27 19:50:00" ...
```

I tried using "autoplot" 
autoplot(forecast(mytsTT2,1000))
[image]

How should i add the fitting and validation area in my autoplot?

Comment: There may be a way to do it with autoplot or with the `ts` object, but I don't know what it is. Are you interested in a method that would require getting the data into a table and using `ggplot`?

Comment: Hi Chris, thanks for reply. Yes, I m interested on getting data into a table and using ggplot. May i know how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to be code that you can just plug and play but here is what you can generally do.

1. Get your forecast into a data frame

   - You can extract the point forecast with something like this: `i.results<-data.frame(fc=as.numeric(forecast(ets,h=mth.days)$mean))` where **ets** is an fitted forecast model.
   - Then you need to join this back with the rest of your data so that you have a column with the original values and a column with forecast values.
2. Make the plot with the shading in the background.

   - Use 'ggplot' with two `geom_line` (and a `geom_point` if you're really trying to match that chart). You can find a lot of information on SO or google to do that.
   - For the shading you can use 2 `geom_ribbon`'s.
   - `geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=0,ymax=MAXVALUE,xmin=STARTYEAR,xmax=FITEND),fill="blue",alpha=0.1)`
   - Substitute the appropriate dates for your data into the capitalized values in this to produce the blue rectangle, then do another one for the validation area. For the ymax you can either manually set it at some # that will be high enough or use a vector where you've dynamically calculated what is required to fill the plot area.